# Merge two images, which shares common part

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, image-processing, qt5

I've got two QImages, which shares a common part for example:

[image]

[image]

And I want to merge them into one like this:

[image]

Could I do it using Qt5 framework? Do I have to use the OpenCV? And how can I handle it?

Comment: I found an example of image stitching in opencv here: http://ramsrigoutham.com/2012/11/22/panorama-image-stitching-in-opencv/

Comment: if you want to use openCV you can try the high-level imagestichter class: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/stitching/doc/high_level.html#stitcher

Comment: I doubt Qt would have such advanced image processing capabilities. Your best bet would probably be to use OpenCV to stitch the images and transfer it to a `QPixmap` using `QPixmap::loadFromData` if you need t use it with other Qt components.